# Modify data according to attributes with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

EDIT :

```
<hero renown="null">John Doe</hero>
<hero gender="%women">"Poppin's</hero>
<hero gender="%God">Till</hero>
```

Thank you very much for your answers, I can get the desired result. With one exception ... For one of the attributes, its value is "%women". I tried a , and many more but no results ...

---

I wish I could with XSLT, select in my data xml only the elements that have a "women" attribute  and therefore do not keep the others.
I have the code below:

```
<hero renown="null">John Doe</hero>
<hero gender="women">"Poppin's</hero>
<hero type="God">Till</hero>
```

And I would like to have this :

```
<women>Poppin's</women>
<god>Till</god>
```

This is what I have already tried:

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//hero">
    <xsl:if test = "attribut = 'gender'">
        <xsl:element name="{@gender}">
            <xsl:value-of select="$hero"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: It is in the spirit of XSLT to use templates and avoid `<xsl:for-each>`. This allows to eliminate conditional statements almost completely. The resulting code is much simpler, shorter (4 lines in this case), flexible for future modification and maintenance and what we call simply *elegant*

Comment: In case you have a multitude of characters to be removed (not only `%`), there is a generic technique of doing this, as shown below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this Code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hero">
  <xsl:for-each select="@*">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(., '%', '')}">
    <xsl:value-of select="..//node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
  </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This code works very well but I lose the child elements. This is the case anyway if I put:

`<xsl:for-each select="@gender">
 <xsl:element name="{translate(., '%', '')}">
  <xsl:call-template name="text">
   <xsl:with-param name="text" select="." />
  </xsl:call-template>
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>`

Comment: i'm not understand please brief

Comment: It's good I managed to solve my problem, thank you very much! : D

Answer (score 2):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="hero[@gender='women']">
    <women><xsl:value-of select="."/></women>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML fragment** (wrapped up into a top element to make it well-formed XML document):

```
<heroes>
  <hero renown="null">John Doe</hero>
  <hero gender="women">Poppin's</hero>
  <hero type="God">Till</hero>
</heroes>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<women>Poppin's</women>
```

---

**Update**:
The OP changed the problem stating that:

> I have a lot of tags with a % in the value of its attribute

**Here is a generic solution**, which removes any non-name-character from the value of the `gender` attribute and constructs an element with that result as its name:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:variable name="vNameChars" select=
  "'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_.'"/>

  <xsl:template match="hero[@gender]">
     <xsl:element name=
     "{translate(@gender, translate(@gender, $vNameChars, ''), '')}">
       <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<heroes>
  <hero renown="null">John Doe</hero>
  <hero gender="%women">"Poppin's</hero>
  <hero gender="me$n">"Poppin's</hero>
  <hero gender="%God">Till</hero>
  <hero gender="AllValid">Hello</hero>
</heroes>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<women>"Poppin's</women>
<men>"Poppin's</men>
<God>Till</God>
<AllValid>Hello</AllValid>
```

**Explanation**:

We use the *double-translate* technique, first suggested by Michael Kay, to find all contained characters that are invalid in a name, and in the outer `translate()` -- remove these.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is this....

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//hero">
    <xsl:if test="@gender='women'">
        <xsl:element name="{@gender}">
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Or better still, do this, to move the condition into the `xsl:for-each` to allow the `xsl:if` to be removed

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//hero[@gender='women']">
    <xsl:element name="{@gender}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Alternatively do this, as there is no need for dynamic element names when you already now you are only selecting a single gender

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//hero[@gender='women']">
    <women>
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </women>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="hero[contains(@gender, 'women')]">
    <women><xsl:value-of select="."/></women>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="hero[contains(@gender, 'God')]">
    <God><xsl:value-of select="."/></God>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This will not be applicable to my case because my real xml is much more complicated and it would mean dozens of templates. Would not there be a way to make a "{@gender - '& # 37;'}" or something like that? or replace the% with ''? Because I'm going to have the same problem to replace '-' with '_'.

Comment: @Epyon what is your new requirement

Comment: I have a lot of tags with a% in the value of its attribute. The attribute is always "gender" but its value changes each time with always a% at the beginning (% women,% god,% sponge etc ...) and the% should not appear in the output xml tag. I do not know if it's very clear ...

Comment: Maybe with the function "translate" ?